# Different vector space structure to an abelian group.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $(V,+)$ be an abelian group. Can we have two multiplication map $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$ from $\mathbb R\times V\to V$ such that $(V, +, \phi_1)$ and $(V, +, \phi_2)$ are two different vector space $( \phi_1\neq \phi_2)$.

Comment: Sorry for bad editing. First time posting from mobile device, will figure out soon..

Comment: The sign you want is $

Comment: In principle it could be possible that the same group $V$ has two distinct structures as a vector space. The problem here is that the base field $\Bbb{R}$ is "too complicated".